# Using property other than 'Id' for primary key in Dapper.net

Tags: dapper

Will Dapper.net work if I am using a property other than "Id" or "id" for the primary key of a table / object?

All I can see in the docs is something about "split on" which I do not follow.

Will it work for mapping inserts, updates & selects without being aware what the primary key is / without having an Id property?

Is anything else going to be different or not work by not having an Id field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will Dapper.net work if I am using a property other than "Id" or "id" for the primary key of a table / object?

Anytime without an issue, dapper will have no issue with this, dapper, being an object mapper, doesn't care much about the primary key

> Except That

When you do Complex object mapping, which contains custom types, then with `Id` it can automatically split in the `Query` call and fill the objects. This is since they need some standard to fill objects, which can be overridden by supplying the `SplitOn`

Comment: Do post, if you have a use case where it cause an issue, I am not aware of any.

Comment: This is what I thought - a mapper just maps - but good to get confirmation thx. Will let you know if issues arise. Out of interest do you think always using "Id" (or some standard naming convention) is a good idea? I am torn between being consistent and using a different field as a primary key as its more logical in this case.

Comment: Not at all, have a primary key which makes sense for a given schema, there's no need to have a mandatory "Id" as PK. If Name is PK, you cannot make it Id, this would be misleading.

Comment: Almost always "Id" makes sense though, in my experience - very occasionally I need something human readable too. Having that predictable consistency is nice however.

Comment: Your choice, but that mostly refers to a Number, in case its a string or alpha numeric, then would be misleading or you may need a Prefix like `RoleId`, `OrderId`, `CustomerId`. Mostly plain `Id` in my experience is used for Identity columns in Sql Server or Sequence in Oracle.

Comment: Yes I would always tie an Id in a C# class to an IDENTITY column in SQL Server. This provides a lot of clarity - hmm...

Comment: If you find the answer useful, do consider voting it up

Comment: As a side note - scaffolding in MVC works slightly less well if Id is not the primary key - you have to manually fill this in for action links. Not a huge deal but if you want to minimise work - using Id helps. "Convention Over Configuration".